# Android: Force Close opening Spinner with ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, xml-parsing, android-spinner

I have a problem, very annoying problem, and I have absolutely no idea what is causing it! I am trying to make an Android application capable of reading an XML file, adding some data from the XML file to an ArrayList, and then putting the ArrayList in a Spinner. Here is part of my Shortcuts class.

> Shortcuts.java

```
Spinner selection = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.shortcutsSpinner); //Defining the Spinner
        /*ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.shortcut_selection, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); //Defining the items in the Spinner
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        selection.setAdapter(adapter); //Setting the items to the Spinner*/
        ArrayList<String> items;
        try {
            items = scanner.getCategorys();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            items = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            items = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            items = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        selection.setAdapter(adapter);

        selection.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                final String simulatorCommands = getString(R.string.Simulator_Commands); //Setting Shortcuts
                final String controlSurfaceCommands = getString(R.string.Control_Surface_Commands);
                TextView Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.shortcutsText);  //Defining the TextView
                Spinner selection = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.shortcutsSpinner); //Defining the Spinner
```

Here is part of my Scanner class

> Scanner.java

```
public ArrayList<String> getCategorys() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        ArrayList<String> categorys = new ArrayList<String>();
        categorys.add("Please select a category");
        //START ADDING HERE
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/fsx_kneeboard/categories.xml");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        parser.next();
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("name")) {
                categorys.add(parser.getText());
            }
            parser.next();
            eventType = parser.getEventType();
        }
        return categorys;

    }
```

I can get into the Scanner activity, but when I try to open the Spinner, I get a force close, and this in the logcat.

> 04-09 17:30:56.452: D/AndroidRuntime(9980): Shutting down VM
>   04-09 17:30:56.452: W/dalvikvm(9980): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7e8)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:376)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:329)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:325)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at com.android.internal.widget.WeightedLinearLayout.onMeasure(WeightedLinearLayout.java:60)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   04-09 17:30:56.482: E/AndroidRuntime(9980):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I don't understand the logcat much, I am new to Java. I know the problem is in this bit of code; when I delete it, the Spinner opens and works showing me 'Please select a category'.

```
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("name")) {
                categorys.add(parser.getText());
            }
            parser.next();
            eventType = parser.getEventType();
        }
```

But that code seems clean to me, any help please? Thanks for you time and help, I will be very grateful, zeokila.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getName%28%29) `parser.getName()` could be null:

> If the current event is not START_TAG, END_TAG, or ENTITY_REF, null is returned.

You could try using this instead: `"name".equals(parser.getName())` so that it returns false if `parser.getName()` is null.

And `int eventType = parser.getEventType();` should probably be in your while loop or its value will not update when you call `parser.next();`.

Comment: I edited the while loop, I had to add eventType = parser.getEventType(); above parser.next();
Now it does not force close, but it will simply show please select a category, but not the extra data in the XML file, thanks for your help though, no data is better than force closes.